# How to use Regular Expression in CLI Bash

Tags: regex, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am using AWS Command Line Interface (CLI) to list some AMI Images from AWS. The Name of an Image is like:

- SVN_backup 12-0
- SVN_backup 11-0
- SVN_backup 10-0
- SVN_backup_9
- SVN_backup_8
- SVN_backup_7

When using:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters 'Name=name,Values="SVN*"' --output text --query 'Images[].[Name,CreationDate]' |awk '{print $1 " " $2}'
```

it works but Doesnt diplay the other Name Has white Space

the Filter is in this attribute `--filters 'Name=name,Values="SVN*"'`

I tried this Regex `SVN_backup.*` but AWS bash doesn't Recognize it

Comment: Bash has no idea if it's an RE or not. it's the `aws` command that handles the string.

Comment: @pynexj even when I create a bash file in Linux and I tired the same regex it doesn't work

Comment: then update your question so it would be a real Bash+RE question.